# cell image view is indented

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, tableview

I am adding images to the table view cells but the images seem to be indented towards the right. How can I adjust so it touches the left wall of cell wall.

[image]

As you can see in the image above their is a little white space of the left side of the icon. It shouldn't be their.

Its being set like so:

```
     cell.imageView?.image = iconArray[indexPath.row]
```

How can I fix this. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve `layoutSubviews`..
Change `self.imageView.frame`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
      [super layoutSubviews];

      self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
}
```